# Vagrant on Windows: SSH and Accessing localhost denied

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to get vagrant setup on my home computer (got it working fine at home).

I get virtualbox and vagrant installed just fine.  I'm able to get the box running (Precise 64; do get a message about guest addon's not matching the virtualbox install).

When I try and do 'vagrant ssh' from Git (in the same directory as my Vagrantfile), as many tutorials recommend, it acts like it's doing something but then won't connect and says something along the lines of "must run vagrant up in order to be able to ssh to this guest'.  However I can ssh via Putty with no problems.  Minor issue I suppose but it would be nice to use git to ssh in. And I do have the linux tools installed and the path set to the bin.

The more problematic one is I'm unable to pull up localhost:8080 in the browser.  Just no page found.  I checked the /var/www/ vs /var/www/html and got that situated, but still no luck.

Do I need to setup a rule in the firewall or disable antivirus?

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but your post is a little confusing to me.  You seem to be describing several problems.  `vagrant up` will start a box specified in a `Vagrantfile`.  If you started a box via some other way (like the virtualbox GUI), vagrant won't know how to ssh to it (of course, putty will be quite happy because you tell it how to connect).  No idea what you mean by "use git to ssh in." And yes, you will need to open 8080 in the guest in order to connect to it, and the `Vagrantfile` might also map that port for you.  HTH!

Comment: It is a couple of questions unfortunately.  However I did get this fixed today.  I changed the port for the web service and got into local host.  As for the SSH from git, not sure what happened there but it is now working...go figure.